# How to pass a struct array to a function

Tags: arrays, c, function, struct

I want to pass a struct array into a function, however, there's something wrong with how I'm passing it and I cant figure out what. I'll include the relevant code.

The Struct:

```
typedef struct fitbit
{
    char patient[10];

} FitbitData;
```

Main.c:

```
FitbitData* data = (FitbitData*)malloc(sizeof(data) * 1450);
count = storeToksInArray(line, count, data);
```

function:

```
 int storeToksInArray(char line[], int count, FitbitData* data[]) 
    {
    strcpy(data[count]->patient, strtok(line, ",")); //name
    puts(data[count]->patient); }
```

I've already tested my code and there aren't any problems with line or count. The array works fine in my main file, but once I pass it into the function I can't get it to store the data correctly. The strcpy and puts functions work fine in main as well, so I'm 90% sure it's how I'm passing the array into the function and then using it in the function. I can also use the strtok and puts functions fine by themselves in the function, but once I try storing the token in the array, it doesn't work.

**Edit: I figured it out! I removed the brackets after FitbitData* data[] to get FitbitData* data and then change -> to .**

Comment: what does `FitbitData` look like? If it has pointers and not arrays you will need to allocate them before copying e.g. `patient`

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> int storeToksInArray(char line[], int count, FitbitData* data[])
> ```

The expression `FitbitData* data[]` means *`data` is an array of pointers to `FitbitData`*. You seem to be wanting instead a pointer to an array of `FitbitData`. But an array type is effectively a pointer, so you don't need to pass a pointer to it. Consider changing your function declaration to:

```
int storeToksInArray(char line[], int count, FitbitData data[])
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that `data` is a `FitbitData` pointer, and yet your function is expecting an *array* of `FitbitData` pointers. Perhaps what you want is either:

```
int storeToksInArray(char line[], int count, FitbitData* data)
```

or

```
int storeToksInArray(char line[], int count, FitbitData data[])
```

Both are equivalent in this context, it's a question of which you prefer or which seems clearer to you. Personally, I prefer the first one.